# What are the number of solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+…+x_n = m$ with $x_i\geq 0$ and $x_i$ is odd?

Tags: combinatorics

What are the number of solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+…+x_n = m$ with $x_i\geq 0$ and $x_i$ is odd?

I know that the number of solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+…+x_n = m$ with $x_i\geq 0$ is ${n+m-1}\choose{m}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not write $x_i=2y_i+1$?

Comment: Thank you! It really helped:)

Comment: I encourage you then to post an answer below utilizing the hint you found helpful.  It helps give you practice, helps us confirm that the hint had the desired impact and that you understood the problem, and helps by letting the system know that the question no longer needs attention from answerers as it already has an answer.

Comment: I'm working on it. Thank you:)

Comment: Then, with @AnginaSeng comment, you just have to use the formula you know on the $y_i$ problem with a $m'=...$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_i=2y_i+1$ where $y_i$ is a non_negative integer number.

Then we are actually looking for the number of solutions to the equation:

$(2y_1+1)+(2y_2+1)+...+(2y_n+1)=m$

$y_1+y_2+...y_n=\frac{m-n}{2}$

Note that if $m$ and $n$ are not both even or not both odd we get that there is no solution for the problem because the sum of integer numbers is also an integer number.

So the number of solutions for the equation $y_1+y_2+...y_n=\frac{m-n}{2}$  if both $m$ and $n$ are even or both are odd is  ${\frac{m+n}{2}-1}\choose{\frac{m-n}{2}}$.